# How to optionally catch a group in Javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, option-type

I have the following 2 variables:

```
var firefox = "Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:32.0) Gecko/32.0 Firefox/32.0"
var chrome = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 4 Build/KTU84Q) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.57 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

I would like to catch from this:

- optionally (if it exists in the string) `Nexus 4`
- `Firefox|Chrome`
- version of the browser

so the resulting strings after the regex replace should be:

- `Firefox 32.0`
- `Nexus 4 Chrome 38.0.2125.57`

I have a regex as follows thus far:

```
var newf = firefox.replace(/^.*(Nexus)?.*(Firefox|Chrome)\/([\d\.]*).*/, "$1 $2 $3")
var newc = chrome.replace(/^.*(Nexus)?.*(Firefox|Chrome)\/([\d\.]*).*/, "$1 $2 $3")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
.*(Nexus 4).*(Chrome\S+).*|.*(Firefox\S+)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/hR4aH9/1)**

[image]

Comment: I need to apply the same regex for each variable (and treat them separately).

Comment: @Patryk it's the same, you can apply the same regex to both values and you will have the specific output. If you treat them together or separatedly will generate the same output.

Comment: I did what you suggested (for each string i did `.replace` with your regex) and I got those 2: `Firefox/32.0` , `Nexus 4 Chrome/38.0.2125.57`